# jQueryUI linked sortables lose drop ability after cloning

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a multi-dimensional unordered list where I want to be able to drag the items or groups around to adjust the order and grouping of the items in the fields. I have set the existing data up and it moves and drops and save perfectly.

I added the ability to clone a blank li and append to the last list, and this also works perfectly.

My issue is when I want to add a new group, it adds fine and the default blank item it comes with also is added, and can be moved to any existing list. The new group however no longer receives drops, and if you start dragging an item out, you can't even drop it back in!

I have tried all sorts of theories and methods, and I'm at a loss. I tossed a lot of the data and made a jsFiddle which shows the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/MJbVz/

If you have a go, you can see that the existing 2 x groups all move happily.  Any added item also moves freely. The existing and new groups can be resorted with ease. But the items in the newly added groups can only move out, not even within.

I'm hoping I've missed something really simple because I need this to work!!